# Getting soap message without invoking web service

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Using Glassfish Metro implementation of JAX-WS specification, is it possible to generate SOAP request message for specific operation without actually invoking the operation. Something like SOAPUI ability to generate sample SOAP message basing just on WSDL only that I would like to generate it providing parameters for operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I've got it. It ain't pretty and it ain't clean as it uses reflection, bases on Oracle proprietary classes and assumes that you've your client side WS part already generated but if you need such functionality as badly as I do with deadline approaching unavoidable like death itself then hear my tale :)

```
// location of wsdl file provided in URL format
// ex. file://localhost/C:/wsdl.wsdl for local file
String wsdlLocation = "wsdlLocation";

try{
    // we're assuming that you've already generated WS client side
    GeneratedService service = new GeneratedService(
        new URL(wsdlLocation),
        new QName("namespaceURI", "localPart"));

    GeneratedPort port = service.getGeneratedPort();

    SEIStub stub = (SEIStub) Proxy.getInvocationHandler(port);

    Field methodHandlersField =
        stub.getClass().getDeclaredField("methodHandlers");
    //hack to make private field accessible
    methodHandlersField.setAccessible(true);

    Method operationMethod = null;
    Object args = null;

    switch (somethingToTellYouWhatMethodToInvoke){
        case someMethodValue:
            operationMethod = GeneratedPort.class.getMethod(
                "methodName", classes, of, your, attributes);
            args = new Object[]{attributes, of, your, method};
            break;
        default:
            throw new SomeException("some message");
            break;
    }

    MethodHandler handler = ((Map<Method, MethodHandler>) methodHandlersField.
        get(stub)).get(operationMethod);

    Method createMessageMethod = handler.getClass().getSuperclass().
        getDeclaredMethod("createRequestMessage", Object[].class);
    //another hack
    createMessageMethod.setAccessible(true);

    Message message = (Message) createMessageMethod.invoke(handler, args);

    Transformer transformer =
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(
        "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    transformer.transform(
        message.readPayloadAsSource(), new StreamResult(System.out));
} catch (Exception e){
    //lots of things to catch
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So once again this is very bad solution but until some heavy thinker comes and saves my day with something better or Sun moves classes I need to more friendly package it has to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

DIY: Point client to a PHP page which dumps the payload. Run the client. It will fail reading the response, but the request will be saved.

Comment: If I wanted to make my application external service dependent then I would just stick to my web service, as Jax WS allows me to add message handler to handler chain, throw RuntimeException from inside of it stopping further operation invoking and catch this exception wherever I want with my message being one of the fields of the Exception. This solution however demands presence of the WS as method invoker connects to WS before my handler has a chance of doing anything. I need the solution that works off-line.